# MySQL | Eloquent - Order by first occurrence then by ID

Tags: mysql, eloquent

I have the following table:

| ID | Main | URL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | foto1.jpg |
| 2 | 1 | foto2.jpg |
| 3 | 0 | foto3.jpg |
| 4 | 0 | foto4.jpg |
| 5 | 1 | foto5.jpg |
| 6 | 0 | foto5.jpg |

I need to order following these rules:

1. First - Most Recent Main Picture  (Just one record, the other mains will be ordered by ID)
2. ID (Most recent first)

So my table should look like this:

| ID | Main | URL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 1 | foto5.jpg |
| 6 | 0 | foto5.jpg |
| 4 | 0 | foto4.jpg |
| 3 | 0 | foto3.jpg |
| 2 | 1 | foto2.jpg |
| 1 | 0 | foto1.jpg |

If I order by main then by ID it will not work because ID 2 will be before ID 6 as it is also a main url.

How can I build this query using MySQL/Eloquent?

Comment: How come ID=5 is older then ID=2? From the rest of the rows it seems the bigger the ID the more recent the row.

Comment: Sorry. The most recent main comes first. I updated my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CROSS JOIN` to a subquery that returns the ID of the *most recent Main* row. Then use the ID of this row in the `ORDER BY` clause of your query:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
CROSS JOIN (
   SELECT ID AS Most_Recent_Main_ID
   FROM Table1
   WHERE Main = 1
   ORDER BY ID DESC
   LIMIT 1  
) t
ORDER BY 
  CASE 
    -- Give precedence to the most recent main ID over all other rows
    WHEN ID = Most_Recent_Main_ID THEN 0
    ELSE 1
  END,
  ID DESC
```

[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/75d6414/7)